# How to use DirectoryCollection in saxon

Tags: java, saxon

Tried creating a directory collection in saxon. How do i add xml files to this collection and run xquery on them.

```
DirectoryCollection dirColl = 
                new DirectoryCollection(saxonConfig, "file:///C:/Users/sasolkar/Desktop/collectTest/", new File("file:///D:/table%20linkbase%20conformance%20suite%20original/table-linkbase-conf-2015-08-12/conf/tests/1000-rule-node/1070-rule-node-occ-rule/"), null);

        Resource r  = dirColl.makeResource(saxonConfig, "file:///D:/table%20linkbase%20conformance%20suite%20original/table-linkbase-conf-2015-08-12/conf/tests/1000-rule-node/1070-rule-node-occ-rule/occ-fragment-overridden-table.xml");
```

Can anyone tell me the process of creatin an in-memory collection of xml files to executexquery on them.

Answer (score 0):

The `DirectoryCollection` class isn't really intended to be used like this. When you use the `collection()` function, Saxon invokes a registered `CollectionFinder` (defaulting to its own `StandardCollectionFinder`.

The `StandardCollectionFinder` will look at the URI passed to the collection() function to see whether it corresponds to the name of a directory in your filestore; if it does, then it will create a `DirectoryCollection` and pass this back to the collection() function. The content of the collection then corresponds to the files found in the directory. If you write your own `CollectionFinder`, then you can do the same thing if you want, or you can create a different kind of `ResourceCollection` if you prefer.

It looks to me as if you are trying to create a collection of files that are NOT all in the same directory, so you want to use some kind of `ResourceCollection` other than a `DirectoryCollection`. I don't think any of the standard implementations of `ResourceCollection` quite does what you are asking for, so you could implement your own, either directly or by extending `AbstractResourceCollection`.

But I wonder if it's better to take a step back and get a clearer picture what you are trying to do. It may be easier not to use collections at all. For example, you could write a query that takes a parameter (external variable) which is a sequence of URIs, which you then fetch with the doc() function; or you could parse the documents externally and supply a sequence of document nodes as the parameter to your query.